# difference between ExportAsFixedFormat2 and ExportAsFixedFormat?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

In PowerPoint VBA, what is the difference between ExportAsFixedFormat2 and ExportAsFixedFormat?

Comment: Workbook.ExportAsFixedFormat is for Office 2007 and Presentation.ExportAsFixedFormat2 is for Office 2013 onwards... Don't you read the documentation?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there are more parameters in the "ExportAsFixedFormat2", see :

ExportAsFixedFormat : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/office/ff746080.aspx 
(they say it is equivalent of Saving as PDF)

ExportAsFixedFormat2 : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/office/jj229507.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The commenters are correct.  More generally, when Office developers add new capabilities to methods like ExportAsFixedFormat between one version and the next, they provide a new method (ie, one with 2 tacked onto its name).

That way your code can call the appropriate method for the version it's running in w/o causing compile errors.